# Which variables does PapPal send when subscription payments are processed periodically

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I've signed for my own subscription, and I've got these messages with from paypal. I displayed txn_type and subscr_date.

```
|    txn_type    |        subscr_date        |
| subscr_payment | NULL                      | 
| subscr_signup  | 05:04:37 May 15, 2017 PDT | 
| subscr_cancel  | 05:05:57 May 15, 2017 PDT |
```

Messages of `txn_type subsrc_payment` only have `subscr_id` and nothing else.

I am interested in what messages will be send when recurring payment gets executed next month, next year...

I suspect there will be just

```
|    txn_type    |        subscr_date        | subscr_id
| subscr_payment | NULL                      | SOME ID HERE
```

Can anyone what kind of txn_type will be sent over? I am having a hard time simulating this process.

Answer (score 0):

When a payment happens then the subscr_payment is the IPN type you would get.  Not sure why you're saying you are only seeing minimal parameters.  Here is a sample of a subscr_payment IPN:

```
Array
(
    [mc_gross] => 5.00
    [protection_eligibility] => Eligible
    [address_status] => unconfirmed
    [payer_id] => 8FXTJQD6PGD5N
    [address_street] => 123 Test Ave.
    [payment_date] => 22:30:42 Jan 04, 2017 PST
    [payment_status] => Completed
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [address_zip] => 11000
    [first_name] => Tester
    [mc_fee] => 0.50
    [address_country_code] => MA
    [address_name] => HAMMA Omar
    [notify_version] => 3.8
    [subscr_id] => I-WCECH3SA87PT
    [payer_status] => unverified
    [business] => receiver@email.com
    [address_country] => Morocco
    [address_city] => Rabat
    [verify_sign] => A3Y1IabViDnLM.hMAUvK-kr83JP5AaoMlP3UYuHFIfHdL4P5lBuXYBoQ
    [payer_email] => payer@email.com
    [txn_id] => 0RF86855U2529745U
    [payment_type] => instant
    [payer_business_name] => Testerson Tester
    [last_name] => Testerson
    [address_state] => Rabat
    [receiver_email] => receiver@email.com
    [payment_fee] => 0.50
    [receiver_id] => G3LWKY98MHFFC
    [txn_type] => subscr_payment
    [item_name] => Times News
    [mc_currency] => USD
    [residence_country] => MA
    [test_ipn] => 1
    [transaction_subject] => Times News
    [payment_gross] => 5.00
    [ipn_track_id] => d95263f949f25
    [ipn_url_name] => AE Sandbox
)
```